# Magento2: Attribute News to date, News from date , special from date and special to date doesn't show in admin

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, special-price, magento-enterprise-2

I've store in  Magento ver. 2.1.4 Enterprise. I am trying to add News to date and special date for products. I can't see it in admin. I've checked and attribute is available but its doesn't show in admin product page.

There is also 1 another problem. I can't set special price for configurable product.

See below screenshot for more detail.

[image]
[image]
Anyone got this kind of issue?

Update:

I've already run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Update:**

When i use mass update for update product attribute i can see dates. see screenshot below. only problem when add/edit product.
[image]

Comment: first of all you have to check attribute set, above is for only set in default attribute set product. first check  product attribute set run indexing command.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I've only 1 attribute set: Default and i've run reindex lots of time.

Comment: Try with just remove var folder and check

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Thanks I've tried that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento intentionally hid these values in Enterprise Edition (see vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/etc/adminhtml/di.xml).

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="attributesToEliminate" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="news_from_date" xsi:type="string">news_from_date</item>
            <item name="news_to_date" xsi:type="string">news_to_date</item>
            <item name="custom_design_from" xsi:type="string">custom_design_from</item>
            <item name="custom_design_to" xsi:type="string">custom_design_to</item>
            <item name="special_from_date" xsi:type="string">special_from_date</item>
            <item name="special_to_date" xsi:type="string">special_to_date</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Per their documentation, they want you to use Scheduled Updates for special price

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-special.html

Comment: Highly recommend checking out @mpchadwick's detailed blog post on the reasoning for this, for those interested: https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-2-enterprise-special-price-confusion

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I've already run this commands. See updated question.

Comment: Try to unassign save reindex & then do reassign & check

Comment: Ankit Thanks. I've tried this as well. but no luck